# Android Emulator Keyboard Acting Funny

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm writing an app for Android 2.3.3 and all of a sudden the emulator no longer takes responses from my physical keyboard. It also refuses to backspace or type numbers with the soft/emu keyboard. It was working fine for the last few hours then all of a sudden... Poof!

I've tried deleting and recreating my emulator, restarting Eclipse, etc. Nothing seems to work and being able to type numbers is crucial to finishing my app. This is what I've been typing in:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/url"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="@string/stream_url" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible fix: just try to restart your computer. I've had this happen to me before. See what happens. If that doesn't help, try to create a new app with just a single text input and see if you can now type. Also, try to change the text input keyboard by long clicking the editText and changing the input.

Comment: I left my pc alone for a while and came back and it seemed to work again. Peculiar. Thanks for the info, mate.